# How do we make sense of this find command?

Tags: find

```
find /path/to/wordpress -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

It seems that it find stuffs whose type is file and then exec chmod

What does `{}` and `\` and `;` is for?

Answer (score 2):

`{}` simply means the file returned by `find`, while `\;` it's the terminator.

Please keep in mind that `\;` means "execute the command *for each* file returned by find".

In your case

```
find /path/to/wordpress -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

means "execute `chmod 664` on each file found under `/path/to/wordpress`.

For example, if you have

```
/path/to/wordpress/file1
/path/to/wordpress/file2
/path/to/wordpress/file3
```

the result is equivalento to call `chmod` three times:

```
chmod 664 /path/to/wordpress/file1
chmod 664 /path/to/wordpress/file2
chmod 664 /path/to/wordpress/file3
```

You can also terminate the command with `\+`, which passes *every* file found as arguments for the command.

With the example above, `find /path/to/wordpress -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \+` is equivalent to a **single** `chmod`:

```
chmod 664 /path/to/wordpress/file1 /path/to/wordpress/file2 /path/to/wordpress/file3
```

Comment: I see and doing it with \; means doing it 3 times

Comment: @J.Chang well, it meas _do it for each file_, it's 3 times because there are 3 files in the example. If there are 1000 files, it will do it 1000 times ;)